# How to retrieve domain of website irrespective of the redirect domains

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch information from the URL provided as an input, I need to fetch the exact domain name irrespective of the redirect URL.
For Example, https://www.example.com is actually hosted on a naked domain, so google will redirect me automatically to https://example.com even when I hit https://www.example.com.

I am using [metainspector](https://github.com/gabceb/node-metainspector) as of now but not able to do retrieve the above-mentioned scenario.
So any help on how to go ahead would be appreciated. Thanks.